# Git bash or NPM on Windows is converting an argument into a path

Tags: node.js, bash, git, mingw

I am writing a node.js script to patch server files. Our development machines are Windows, but the servers are Linux.

When I execute run the following script:

`npm run patch-file --source-file "/path/to/file" --destination "/path/to/file"`

Somewhere between Git bash or NPM the arguments are converted to windows paths. Which I don't want to happen here. I am handling the path conversion based on the source/ destinaiton in the script itself.

**Actual Output:**

`node ./scripts/patch-file.js "--source-file" "C:/Git/path/to/file" "--destination" "C:/Git/path/to/file"`

**Expected output:**

`node ./scripts/patch-file.js "--source-file" "/path/to/file" "--destination" "/path/to/file"`

**Notes**

This seems to be isolated to Git bash, I can't replicate it using windows command prompt or powershell. I'd still like to figure this out, because I would like this to work seemlessly between command terminals.

Comment: As explained in the question I linked, you can pass double slash `//` in the argument to prevent msys from expanding it to the path.
The issue is though: it works fine when you issue it from the console yourself, but becomes problematic when you want to have a portable bash script. Then you need to have an if-else in your bash script with `/` for normal case and `//` and for Windows-bash case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/msys2-runtime/pull/11) or [here](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/673).

I did a test with `notepad.exe`. While this worked and opened the text file from the root of the *Git for Windows* installation

```
notepad.exe /LICENSE.txt
```

suggesting that the path conversion took place, this failed with `notepad.exe` complaining that the file `/LICENSE.txt` couldn't be found

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 notepad.exe /LICENSE.txt
```

So, I think that the latter form is what you need.

Note that `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` seems to be really specific to *Git for Windows* and is not available in other MSYS2-based terminals.